# Responsive zigzag grid in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve the following:

**Big screen:**

First row: image and text to the right of it

Second row: text and image to the right of it

Third row: image and text to the right of it

**Small screens**

First row: text and image below it

Second row: text and image below it

Third row: text and image below it

Not sure what the ideal way of doing this would be? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This approach.. Which looks right on desktop:

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm"><img src=""></div>
  <div class="explainertext col-sm"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="explainertext col-sm"></div>
  <div class="col-sm"><img src=""></div>
</div>

Comment: @ask please add the code with proper formatting to your question.

Comment: Look for reordering of columns: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#reordering

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the columns full width for mobile. In order to do so, use **`col-12`** for all of them.

You just need to reorder the first and last img columns.Use **`order-last`** and **`order-sm-0`** for them.

> There are also responsive .order-first and .order-last classes that change the order of an element by applying order: -1 and order: 13 (order: $columns + 1), respectively. These classes can also be intermixed with the numbered .order-* classes as needed. - [Bootstrap-order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-sm col-12 order-last order-sm-0">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
    <div class="explainertext col-sm col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolor nesciunt sequi sed tenetur sapiente nihil ratione soluta, ullam delectus architecto cupiditate. Minus tenetur fugiat perferendis. Perferendis impedit doloremque aspernatur?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border my-3">
    <div class="explainertext col-sm col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat eius hic nihil ut velit odio autem debitis maxime modi repudiandae itaque, inventore quod amet dolore optio adipisci maiores non corporis?
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-12">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-sm col-12 order-last order-sm-0">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
    <div class="explainertext col-sm col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolor nesciunt sequi sed tenetur sapiente nihil ratione soluta, ullam delectus architecto cupiditate. Minus tenetur fugiat perferendis. Perferendis impedit doloremque aspernatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## update

To reorder the columns for small size screens and below, use `col-md` instead of `col-sm` and `order-sm-last order-md-0` for the second text column.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-md col-12 order-last order-sm-0">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
    <div class="explainertext col-sm col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolor nesciunt sequi sed tenetur sapiente nihil ratione soluta, ullam delectus architecto cupiditate. Minus tenetur fugiat perferendis. Perferendis impedit doloremque aspernatur?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border my-3">
    <div class="col-md col-12 order-sm-last order-md-0">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat eius hic nihil ut velit odio autem debitis maxime modi repudiandae itaque, inventore quod amet dolore optio adipisci maiores non corporis?
    </div>
    <div class="col-md col-12">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-md col-12 order-last order-sm-0">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
    <div class=" col-md col-12 ">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dolor nesciunt sequi sed tenetur sapiente nihil ratione soluta, ullam delectus architecto cupiditate. Minus tenetur fugiat perferendis. Perferendis impedit doloremque aspernatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mahan. Looks good. Do you have any idea what I should change in the order so that the text appears underneath the images on small screens?